# Writing pandas/numpy statements in python functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am working on multiple data sets with similar data attributes (column names) in jupyter notebook. But it is really tiresome to run all the commands again and again with multiple data sets to achieve the same target. Can anyone let me know if I can automate the process and run this for various data sets. Let's say I'm running following commands for one data set in jupyter notebook:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r"/d/newfolder/test.csv",low_memory=False) <br>
data.head()

list(data.columns)

data_new=data.sort_values(by='column_name')
```

Now I'd want to run all the commands saving in one function, for different data sets in the notebook.

Can anyone help me out pls on what are the possible ways? Thanks in advance

Comment: why did you write `list(data.columns)
` do you want to sort all columns or specific column  ?

Comment: These are just the sample statements, not specifically to run these. But, Yes @Clegane I'd want to see the columns first and then sort all the columns. My main intention is to run few pandas statements line by line defining them in a function and run this function for various datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, your issue is that something like `print(df)` doesn't show as pretty as if you just have `df` as the last line in a Jupyter cell.

You can have the pretty output whenever you want (as long as your jupyter is updated) by using `display`!

Modifying your code:

```
def process_data(file):
    data = pd.read_csv(file, low_memory=False)
    display(data.head())
    display(data.columns)
    data_new = data.sort_values(by='column_name')
    display(data_new.head())


process_data(r"/d/newfolder/test.csv")
```

This will output `data.head()`, `data.columns`, and `data_new.head()` from a single cell~